# Xcode and iOS SDK in iPad Air

Tags: ios, ipad, xcode

I am a web developer looking to get started with apps for iPhone and iPad.

I have only an iPad Air 16GB. Can I install Xcode 5 and iOS SDK in the iPad for testing, while I code using a Windows PC?

Comment: To run Xcode (with the iOS SDK or OS X SDK), you need a Mac. You can't run Xcode on Windows or on the iPad. Apple does not provide any programming applications that run on an iPhone or iPad. See https://developer.apple.com/xcode/

Answer (score 4):

You cannot install Xcode on iPad Air. You need to have a Mac to develop for iOS devices using Xcode and iOS SDK.

Answer (score 2):

You can, but you'll need an OS X machine running and connected to the Internet in order to compile the builds for your iPad.

This is exactly how the [Dringend app](http://dringend.cc/) works.  It runs on your iPad as a slimmed-down 3rd-party Xcode replacement *(it even understands `.xcodeproj` files!)*, and uses Xcode via a remote OS X host to do the dirty-work.

I thought I read something somewhere about another start-up working towards a product with the same premise, but provides the OS X build-machines as a paid service— I'll update this if I find their name.  Until then, there's always [OS X hosting](https://www.google.com/search?q=os+x+hosting).

Comment: @NimeshNeema _Please don't completely rewrite other people's answers.  This is not a wiki; this is a forum of experts, with their own writings (in the form of questions and answers) which represent their public character.  You're welcome to suggest edits that offer minor technical and formatting corrections, but please do not take the liberty of being the editor of other people's writing.  That is not your role, and the brevity you value is not valued by all._